# MyBatis - constructorArgs annotation and embedded objects

Tags: mybatis

Is it possible to map embedded object with annotation using MyBatis in one query i.e.:
Foo class:

```
public class Foo //immutable
{
private final Integer fooId;
private final String fooAttr;
private final Bar bar;
public Foo(Integer fooId, String fooAttr, Bar bar) //constructor
}
```

Bar class:

```
 public class Bar { //immutable
 private final Integer barId;
 private final String barAttr;
 public Bar(Integer barId, String barAttr) //constructor
}
```

Table FooBar:

```
- INT foo_id
- CHAR foo_attr
- INT bar_id
- CHAR bar_attr
```

Query:

```
@ConstructorArgs({
  @Arg(column="foo_id", javaType=Integer.class),
  @Arg(column="foo_attr", javaType=String.class),
  Bar ?
})
Select("select * from FooBar where foo_id=#{fooId}"
public Foo getFooBy(@Param("fooId") Integer fooId);
```

How to map Bar class as Foo constructor argument (without using subqueries) ?

Answer (score 3):

I know, this is painful, but the following will work:

```
@ConstructorArgs({
  @Arg(column="foo_id", javaType=Integer.class),
  @Arg(column="foo_attr", javaType=String.class),
  @Arg(column="bar_id", javaType=Integer.class),
  @Arg(column="bar_attr", javaType=String.class)
})
```

The constructor should then look like this:

```
public Foo(Integer fooId, String fooAttr, Integer barId, String barAttr)
    this.fooId = fooId;
    this.fooAttr = fooAttr;
    this.bar = new Bar(barId, barAttr);
}
```

You could even leave Bar empty, if the ID is not set:

```
public Foo(Integer fooId, String fooAttr, Integer barId, String barAttr)
    this.fooId = fooId;
    this.fooAttr = fooAttr;
    if (barId != null) {
        this.bar = new Bar(barId, barAttr);
    }
}
```